# Kusto use each value in a list, in another query

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a table - table1 which has columns "Message" of type string and "Timestamp" of type datetime. From table1, I need to get the timestamps of all logs that have a certain Message in the last 1 day. For each timestamp in this list, I need to find the first log in table1 that has a timestamp greater than this timestamp, is within 10 min of this timestamp and has a certain Message.

This is what I have so far:

```
let table1_timestamps = table1
| where Timestamp > ago(1d)
| where Message == "Sample message"
| summarize make_list(Timestamp);
```

Now, for each value in table1_timestamps, I want to run the following query:

```
table1
| where Timestamp between (<timestamp in table1_timestamps> .. 10m)
| where Message == "Different message"
| arg_min(Timestamp)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share sample input and expected results data.

Answer (score 0):

I have used sample data and used below sample query to achieve the result.

**Sample query**

```
let tbl1 = datatable (timeStamp : datetime , message :string )
[
datetime(2023-04-16 11:14:58.4785756),"Sample message",
datetime(2023-04-16 12:15:28.4785869),"Sample message1",
datetime(2023-04-16 12:18:28.4785869),"Sample message",
datetime(2023-04-16 12:27:28.4785869),"Sample message1",
datetime(2023-04-16 13:16:36.2785756),"Sample message",
datetime(2023-04-16 13:25:36.2785756),"Sample message1",
datetime(2023-04-16 13:22:36.2785756),"Sample message1",
datetime(2023-04-16 09:17:12.6785756),"Sample message",
datetime(2023-04-16 09:27:12.6785756),"Sample message1",
datetime(2023-04-16 09:25:11.3785756),"Sample message1",
datetime(2023-04-16 09:18:11.3785756),"Sample message",
datetime(2023-04-16 10:21:09.8785756),"Sample message2",
];
let tbl1_timeStamp = tbl1
| where timeStamp > ago(1d) and message == "Sample message"
| project timeStamp;
tbl1
| join kind = leftouter tbl1_timeStamp on timeStamp
| where timeStamp between (timeStamp .. 10m ) and message == "Sample message1"
| extend dateTime = strcat(datetime_part("year",timeStamp), "-", datetime_part("month",timeStamp), "-", datetime_part("day",timeStamp), ":" , datetime_part("hour",timeStamp))
| summarize arg_min(timeStamp,*) by dateTime
| project-away dateTime, timeStamp1
```

**Result**

[image]